# Finding path and filename from file and printing it

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a text file which is not suitable for splitting and I want to print out the path and filename from each file.

Lines can look like this:

```
"sometextC:\folder\folder\filename.exesometext"
"sometext C:\folder\filename.exe sometext"
```

and so on...

I want something like this:

```
for line in inputFile.readlines():
    hit = find everything between C:\ and .exe
    print hit
```

output should look like this:

```
C:\folder\folder\file.exe 
C:\folder\file.exe
```

WHERE folder and file is changed with whatever is found in the text.  Sorry if my first post was a bit unclear.  Number of parent dirs etc can vary a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what kind of regular expressions you have used?

Comment: http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/regex-that-matches-path-filename-and-extension/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first approximation, you could use [`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.finditer) to find things that might be paths. The example shown below might also match things which are not valid paths (and I'm not strong on the rules for paths on Windows, so you should test that this does what you want thoroughly):

```
contents = inputFile.read()
for path in re.finditer("(C:\\.*?\.exe)", contents):
    print path
```

Comment: Using for path in re.finditer("(C:\\\.*?\.exe)", contents): gave me this when printing path: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1234567>.  I want it to print all the paths with filename as it finds them.

Comment: using print path.groups() got me the result i wanted. Just by using strips i think i can solve this one.  Feel free to give me a "one-liner" for this one if you can.  Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
for path in re.finditer("(C:\Users\Default\thanks.exe)", contents):
print path
```

to print the path